# Using Gmail SMTP servers with JavaMail: Must issue a STARTTLS command first (JavaMail version 1.4.1)

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, gmail-api, starttls

I have read a whole lot of stuff on internet and the suggested questions before posting, but couldn't find anything that works for me.

- JavaMail FAQ on using gmail
- Stackoverflow questions
- JavaMail tutorials
- Any other results from google searches

For the past 5 days, I've been looking for a solution to this and just couldn't find one.

Related Code:

```
private void sendMail(){

  final String username = "foo";
  final String password = "bar";

  Properties props = System.getProperties();
  props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true); // added this line
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
  props.put("mail.smtp.user", username);
  props.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
  props.put("mail.debug", "true");

  Session session = Session.getInstance(props,null);
  MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

  System.out.println("Port: "+session.getProperty("mail.smtp.port"));

  // Create the email addresses involved
  try {
    InternetAddress from = new InternetAddress(username);
    message.setSubject("Yes we can");
    message.setFrom(from);
    message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("ardilgulez@gmail.com"));

    // Create a multi-part to combine the parts
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

    // Create your text message part
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    String htmlMessage = "Our html text";
    messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlMessage, "text/html");

    // Add html part to multi part
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // Associate multi-part with message
    message.setContent(multipart);

    // Send message
    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", username, password);
    System.out.println("Transport: "+transport.toString());
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
  } catch (MessagingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

}
```

Mail Debug Log File:

DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.1
.....
DEBUG: !anyLoaded

DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.address.map

DEBUG: not loading file: C:\Java\JDK16~1.0_4\jre\lib\javamail.address.map

DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Java\JDK16~1.0_4\jre\lib\javamail.address.map (The system cannot find the file specified)

Port: 587

DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]

DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false

DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP t2sm2978726wme.0 - gsmtp

DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 587

EHLO FOO

250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [212.156.0.126]

250-SIZE 35882577

250-8BITMIME

250-STARTTLS

250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES

250-PIPELINING

250-CHUNKING

250 SMTPUTF8

DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"

DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""

DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""

DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""

DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""

DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""

DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""

Transport: smtp://foo@smtp.gmail.com

DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false

MAIL FROM: < foo >

530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. t2sm2978726wme.0 - gsmtp

DEBUG SMTP: got response code 530, with response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. t2sm2978726wme.0 - gsmtp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using a **VERY** old version of JavaMail, you need to use this:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

Notice the quote marks.

Better yet, [upgrade to a current version](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

Oh, and there is no mail.smtp.password property, and you don't need the mail.smtp.host and mail.smtp.user properties since you're passing them to the connect method explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) now log says TLS is ready and stuff, but I'm now getting AuthenticationFailedException and gmail sent me an email about how I'm trying to log in to my account using outdated security standards. The way I read this is that TLS is the new standard and SSL is legacy. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: That plus allowing less secure apps to access solves it: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps