# SMTPSendFailedException and MailConnectException while sending mail using java mail api

Tags: spring-boot, maven, smtp, jakarta-mail, sendmail

Trying to send an email using java mail Api and I keep getting `SMTPSendFailedException`
this is the complete error:

```
org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. d5-20020a170902c18500b00194c90ca320sm6172077pld.204 - gsmtp

    at org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2422)
    at org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1839)
    at org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1316)
```

Here is the function `sendEmail()`

```
public void sendEmail(List<String> to, String subject, String body){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        session.setDebug(false);
        try {
            // create a message
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            InternetAddress[] addresses = new InternetAddress[to.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < to.size(); i++) {
                addresses[i] = new InternetAddress(to.get(i));
            }
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addresses);
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setText(body, "utf-8");
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", username, appPassword);//CAUSES EXCEPTION
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
//            transport.send(msg);
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
            Exception ex = null;
            if ((ex = mex.getNextException()) != null) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

`username` and `appPassword` are global variable.

When I use `transport.send(msg)` instead of `transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients())` I get the following error:

```
org.eclipse.angus.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2258)
    at org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:753)
    at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:342)
    at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:222)
    at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:171)
    at jakarta.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:230)
    at jakarta.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:100)
```

though I am using `port 587` I get this error.
I am using this dependency for java mail api:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.angus</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

*I have tried almost everything from stack overflow and chatGPT but unable to find a solution*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Gmail SMTP servers with JavaMail: Must issue a STARTTLS command first (JavaMail version 1.4.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33523051/using-gmail-smtp-servers-with-javamail-must-issue-a-starttls-command-first-jav)

Answer (score 0):

Send port number as the second argument to the connect() method.

> transport.connect(host, 587, username, password);